# NPM + React: Does not refresh after changes to App.js

Tags: reactjs, npm, three.js

I understand that react should "just work" from this perspective:

```
npm create-react-app
npm run build
```

However, I have found that when I am using `WebGL` with Three.js, I may make changes to `App.js` and find that refreshing the page does not evaluate the new changes.

Instead, I must kill the site and rebuild.

Is there some reason related to underlying dependencies that causes this, or is this unexpected behavior that is worth investing time to fix?

For example:

```
// Working App.js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import * as THREE from "three";
class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    // document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    // use ref as a mount point of the Three.js scene instead of the document.body
    this.mount.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffff00 } );
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( cube );
    camera.position.z = 5;
    var animate = function () {
      requestAnimationFrame( animate );
      cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
      cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
      renderer.render( scene, camera );
    };
    animate();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={ref => (this.mount = ref)} />
    )
  }
}
export default App
```

If I change the following line:

```
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffff00 } );

// to

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
```

I must kill the site and rebuild to observe a color change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Linux, your project is hitting your system's file watchers limit

To fix this, on your terminal, try:

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```